# MSE for multivariate regression

Tags: matlab, model-evaluation, mse, multivariate-regression

I found that the code for computing `mse` for multivariate regression is as below in matlab:

> perf = sum(sum(e.^2)) / numel(e);

where `e`s are residuals.

That is kind of awkward for me because the more you have responses columns the more your `mse` error would be.

My question is that if we account for the number of responses for computing error?

something like below:

> perf = sum(sum(e.^2)) / (numel(e) * m) ;

where `m` in the number of response columns.

Comment: [Related](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/109504/73930), I think

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The numel function in MATLAB is the number of elements, so for a matrix it's not just the number of rows. I suspect the original expression already addresses the concerns you have.